# Learning objective-c/swift from a javascript/angularjs background

Tags: javascript, objective-c, swift

This question might need some background. I currently work at a software development company, we have all manner of developers from front-end to back-end, from javascript to python to objective-c/swift etc etc. I was hired to develop html/css, javascript, and occasionally api's in python. I even went to a bootcamp style school for javascript.

Now, my boss wants me to start developing Apple IOS apps, he knows I have no idea how to do so and is totally cool with my getting paid to train to use things like Xcode, Objective-c and Swift. The reason behind the change is we have too many javascript developers and not enough IOS developers. So far, this learning process has been majorly hands off from the lead and boss' perspective.

I have been combing the internet for different tutorials and walkthroughs for Swift (as that's what they would like me to concentrate on) and have been finding some decent ones. I did run through "A Swift Tour" off of Apples main site for the language and that was pretty easy to follow along, also, I have been running through a bunch of youtube tutorials, and while those can be good, most if not all of the ones I have found seem to be out of date (even month old ones) to the point where if I follow along my test app will not function. At this point I am having a bit of trouble finding good solid tutorials that are up to date and can teach me a lot, the docs are helpful when I know exactly what I want to do, but just reading through them for the sake of learning is like trying to hold water in a sieve, it goes through one ear and out the other.

How do I learn a newer language when most of the tutorials found online are out of date? Where do I look for solid up to date resources?

Comment: Are you looking for Objective-c tutorials or swift?

Comment: Swift, but I was under the impression that a general knowledge base of Objective-c was somewhat required to learn Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

First, i know there are a lot of tutorials out there and some are good and some are not.
I can give you the process i went thru on learning iOS.

1) Stanford iOS Development curses on iTunes - they update every year and according to iOS versions - [Link1](https://itunes.apple.com/il/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550) [Link2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099)

2) apple docs - there is tons of info in the Apple docs (you can read the guides) - [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/)

3) WWDC Videos - [Link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/)

4) tutorial sites like [rayWanderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) [appCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/) have really good tutorials and helpful informations.

I think that with your coding background you can go from here 
Good luck!

Comment: Wow, those first two links are quite extensive, and they are free. Thank you so much for that.

Comment: Glad to help my friend :)